# Prevent Hyperlinks in Microsoft Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365

I am working with Office365, and I am editing a document that URLs are posted in.  However, I do not want these to ever be hyperlinked for security reasons.  I know that some users view this document through the web portal, so I can't use a VBA script to stop it.  Are there any other ways to prevent URLs from becoming hyperlinks? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

- Open the worksheet containing the hyperlinks in Excel.
- Press
  <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
  to go into the VBA editor
- Locate the "Immediate" pane on bottom-left and click in it.
  If you don't see it, press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
- Type this into the Immediate window:

  ```
  Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
  ```
- Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
- All the hyperlinks on the sheet should now be converted to plain text.
- Save the spreadsheet (don't overwrite the original file).

Note that this will not block users from copying manually the links
and open them in their browser.

Comment: This is a great solution! I wish I could get Excel to not create hyperlinks in the first place, when I type a text that looks even remotely like a link (CTRL+Z undoes the conversion, but it’s annoying extra effort).